# Connection timed out only for wikmedia api on server but works on local

Tags: java, rest, connection, server, wikipedia

Following piece of code was working for the last three years, but all of a sudden it throws connection timed out only in server, but works as intended in localhost. 
Any comments ?

```
    public  String getWikiContent(String query) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    String path = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=1&explaintext=1&titles=" + query + "&format=json&redirects";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(path);

        HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/json");

        if (urlConn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new IOException(urlConn.getResponseMessage());
        }

        InputStream is = urlConn.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;

        while ((line = buff.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder.toString();
   }
```

Comment: Perhaps a routing issue?  Can you `curl` the URL from the server environment, independently of the code above?

Comment: `curl` works fine and gives the output as before, only the java fails :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reasons its a network issue, just adding a proxy server fixed it.

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(url,port));
URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection(proxy);
```